# Sendgrid emails array included in the header

Tags: php, email, sendgrid

I run this script to send to each user an email. Mails are sent ok(one to each user), but in the email sent all the others adresses are shown in the headers.

```
$all_users = array(); // intialzie array

while ($usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$usermail = $usuario['email']; 
$hash = $usuario['hash'];
mysqli_query($dbc, "UPDATE newsletter SET enviado = '1' WHERE email='$usermail' "); 

$all_users[] = $usermail; // push all emails first
}

// then send

try {
$email->setTos($all_users)
->setFrom("no_responder@test.com.ar")
->setFromName("test")
->setReplyTo("no_responder@test.com.ar")
->setSubject("Test")
->setHtml('test');

$result = $sendgrid->send($email);
echo "enviado";

} catch(\SendGrid\Exception $e) {
echo $e->getCode() . "\n";
foreach($e->getErrors() as $er) {
    echo $er;
}
}

?>
```

**How can i hide other emails while sending them individually using sendgrid (bcc - blind carbon copy)?**

Comment: Already tried, error 400 Missing destination email

Comment: you still have to have at least ONE `To:`. send it to yourself, or a blackhole address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated your [SendGrid PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php)? The newest version uses [v3 of the WebAPI](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html), which corrects the confusing To: array functionality.

The issue is that what you're doing right now is populating the native SMTP-level To, which is why you can see all the addresses. In the v2 API, you'd need to instead populate the `x-smtpapi` field's `to` array, to make sure SendGrid [splits out all the addresses](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html#-send).

I'd strongly recommend updating your PHP Library & leveraging the v3 API, which removes this confusion, and lets you setup each recipient in a more logical manner.

Comment: Is there anything i should change to the start of the script? require("sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

$sendgrid = new SendGrid('myapikey');

$email    = new SendGrid\Email();

Comment: this is the version i have according to the changelog, v3.2.0

Comment: Per [the readme](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/README.md) the latest version of the library is 5, and requires a recent version of PHP as well. You'll need to then rebuild your script to use the new functions.